# Need to host another application on server with EE

Tags: ee2, htaccess

I have an EE instance on a server and need to host another PHP application in a subdirectory off the htdocs directory.

How would I adjust the .htaccess to allow this application to run without going through EE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have EE installed in root directory and another php applications in sub directory named "domains". All other sites in Codeigniter, WP, EE are inside this directory.

I just write 1 line to tell htaccess to ignore the "domains" folder for checking the rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(domains)($|/) - [L]
```

Let me know if you have any confusion and need the full code of htaccess

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard rewrite rules for EE:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This line:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Means it will ignore folders from the rewrite, therefore won't add /index.php to the beginning of your URL so EE won't manage your URLs and the folder you specify (your other app) will have control and be called.

[EE Documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html)